# iPad Modal Form View Not

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

I am using this code in `didSelectRowAtIndex`.  On my iPhone it pushes a view, on the iPad I want it to present a view modaly in a small popup.  For some reason, on my iPad it is presenting modally but its still full screen rather than a small modal popup.  So the if statement IS working and I use something similar to present a navigation controller elsewhere and it works fine.

Any ideas?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (NSClassFromString(@"UISplitViewController") != nil && UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) 
    {
        DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.navigationController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
        self.navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
        [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
        [detailViewController release];
    }
    else 
    {
        DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
        [detailViewController release];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You set modalTransitionStyle and modalPresentationStyle on the wrong object. You should set them both on detailViewController instead of self.navigationController.

Edit: here is the complete code along with navigation bar that as done button which will dismiss the modal view:

```
DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];
navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

UIBarButtonItem *doneBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                                               target:self
                                                                               action:@selector(modalViewDone)];
detailViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneBarButton;
detailViewController.navigationItem.title = @"Details";
[doneBarButton release];

[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
[detailViewController release];
[navController release];
```

And you need to implement this method:

```
- (void)modalViewDone
{
    [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i did that, but there is now no navbar with a navbutton to dismiss it.  What is the best way to add this?  Should I make a new detailViewController xib? Because on the iPhone, the detailview is just pushed onto the nav stack so the back button is there automatically.

Comment: I have updated my answer with complete code you need, take a look above.